# Is the "Rocket Chip on Zynq FPGAs" Github Repo still working?

Tags: riscv

I am totally new to the RISC-V work. I am intending to implement the rocket core on an FPGA. The FPGAs available in hands at the meantime are:

- Xilinx ZCU104 Evaluation Kit
- ZC702 Evaluation Kit
- VC 709 Connectivity Kit

So, I believe that this [GitHub repo](https://github.com/ucb-bar/fpga-zynq) is going to be useful to me. I know it is no longer maintained, however, I am still wondering if it is efficiently functional with the current release of the [Rocket Chip](https://github.com/chipsalliance/rocket-chip).

Thanks.